# How do you specify from the AWS CLI/API what VPC an RDS Snapshot is restored to?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli, amazon-vpc

I have 2 VPCs, one default and one for my DBs. If I run this command:

```
aws rds restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot --db-instance-identifier test --db-snapshot-identifier db-arn --vpc-security-group-ids "foo"
```

It will produce the error below:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot operation: The DB instance and EC2 security group are in different VPCs. The DB instance is in vpc-a and the EC2 security group is in b
```

Looking at the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateDBInstance.html) it outlines

> For the CLI and API, you specify the VPC security group IDs.

So how do you actually specify in the API/CLI what VPC to create the DB in? In my scenario, it always attempts to create in the default VPC.

Comment: You need to specify the `--db-subnet-group-name` parameter

Comment: The VPC is inferred. This is a common pattern in AWS. When the VPC can be inferred from some other provided data, e.g. a subnet., then there's no need, and in fact no option, to supply the VPC.

Answer (score 3):

According to the following AWS documention [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot.html), you should be able to use `--db-subnet-group-name` parameter to specify the VPC that the restored RDS instance should be created in.

```
aws rds restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot \
  --db-instance-identifier test \
  --db-snapshot-identifier db-arn \
  --db-subnet-group-name my-vpc-subnet-group \
  --vpc-security-group-ids sg-1234567890
```

Replacing the values withy our own.